# How to keep App awake on Heroku using free dyno

Tags: heroku

As the title suggests, how can I prevent my App going to sleep after 30 mins of inactivity (without paying)?

I have a separate .js file making a request to the App through worker dyno every 25 mins or so but it doesn't seem to work.

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

const http = require('http').Server(app)

setInterval(() => {
    http.get("https://myAppURL.herokuapp.com/")
}, 1500000)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Kaffeine](https://kaffeine.herokuapp.com/) to keep the Web Dyno alive.

You can also use a worker but you need to deploy it standalone (on its own Dyno): when deployed alongside a Web Dyno the worker will also go to sleep when the Web Dyno reaches the inactivity timeout.